# Add SharePoint list item, but not view

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I need to restrict a SharePoint list to some users where they all users can add items, but only members of a certain group should be able to view the items.

Is this possible?

I have an html form for creating the item.

Alternatively, can an Infopath form allow users to add item, but not view them?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to handle this would be using Item-level permissions. You can turn this on under the lists advanced settings:

[image]

The users will still be able to see items in the list, but only the ones they created themselves.

Comment: But this would be enforced for all users, right?
I want to have an elevated group and also an admin group both of which should be able to see all items.

Comment: Check what it says to the left, users with more rights can see all items.

Comment: To elaborate on this, the standard **Full Control**, **Approve**, **Design** and **Manage Hierarchy** permission levels can see all the items in the list. **Contribute** and **Edit** (and Read...) can not.

Answer (score 0):

If the users have add items permission, they should be able to view the items.

As a workaround, You could use workflow to remove the group permssion on the items after they are created. Thus the specific group would not be able to view the items.

[image]